# Why producer in Collections.max() is a bounded wildcard?

Tags: java, generics, collections, wildcard

I'm trying to proove on example that each fragment in `Collections.max` declaration is necessary to achieve maximum flexibility.

**In what situation, bound on `Collection` wildcard is necessary?** (signature simplified)

`public <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll)`

versus

`public <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<T> coll)`

I know about PECS rule, but every example I can think of works the same with second declaration and I am looking for example to proove that second `extends` i necessary.

Someone proposed the answer that `max()` must accept `Collection<? extends Something>` but it accepts even without questionable bound:

`public static class Animal implements Comparable<Animal> {`

Created collection from response and passed it to `extends`-less method:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<T> coll) {...}
...
Collection<? extends Animal> someAnimalCollection = new ArrayList<Animal>();
Animal u = max(someAnimalCollection);
```

No errors, no warnings.

Comment: See [Mark Peters' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2907411/697449) on the linked question. Make sure to ignore the accepted answer, which is irrelevant.